# In the context of Dynkin system D, is D \ $\emptyset$ the universal set $\Omega$?

Tags: measure-theory

A [Dynkin system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system), is a collection of subsets of another universal set ${\displaystyle \Omega }$ satisfying a set of axioms weaker than those of σ-algebra.

here is one of the Definitions that wiki gives

> Let Ω be a nonempty set, and let ${\displaystyle D}$ be a collection
>   of subsets of Ω. Then D is a Dynkin system if
>
> 1. Ω ∈ D
> 2. if A ∈ D, then $A^c$ ∈ D
> 3. if $A_1, A_2, A_3, ...$ is a sequence of subsets in D such that $A_i ∩
>     A_j$ = Ø, for all i ≠ j, then  ${\displaystyle \bigcup _{n=1}^{\infty
>     }A_{n}\in D} $

The book "Infinite Dimensional Analysis: A Hitchhiker's Guide" gives a set

> X = {1,2,3,4}.

and claims

> A = {$\emptyset$, {1,2},{3,4},{1,3},{2,4},X} is a Dynkin system that is neigher an algebra nor a π-system

in this case, is the universal set $\Omega$ {{1,2},{3,4},{1,3},{2,4},X}, namely, is D \ $\emptyset$ the universal set $\Omega$?

Comment: $\Omega$ is same as $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the universal set is $X = \{1,2,3,4\}$

So the Dynkin system, as the definition, is a collection of subsets of $X$.

$A$ is a Dynkin system by checking the definition. (1) it contains the universal set $X$ (2) it is closed under complement operation (3) union of mutual disjoint elements in $A$ is still in $A$.

$A$ is not a $\pi$-system since it is not closed under finite intersection: $\{1,2\}\cap\{2,4\} = \{2\}\notin A$

$A$ is not an algebra since it is not closed under finite union: $\{1,2\}\cup\{2,4\} = \{1,2,4\}\notin A$

Answer (score 0):

the definition of Dynkin system is wrong here. For (ii) it should say if $A,B\in \mathcal D$ and $A \subseteq B$ then $B\backslash A \in \mathcal D$. Notice $B \backslash A = A \cap A^c$.